# How to use "include("/includes/header.php");" on MAMP (MAC)

Tags: php, include, mamp, server

I installed the MAMP Server for MAC today and I'm having some issues when I try to use the command "include(".....");" to header, footer and some another pages. The funny thing is: when I just write ONE INCLUDE (for example, the header), it shows normally. But when I write more than one include at the same page (like index.php which has more than 2 includes), just show the first one.

Anyone knows why and how can I fix it?

CODE:

It is:

```
/* <?php

include("/includes/header.php");

?>

<?php

include("/includes/footer.php");

?> */
```

Thanks.

Comment: Post the code too so we can have a look.

Comment: `include` operates with the filesystem, not with the website's root. `include(”/includes/header.php“);` is looking for file starting from the root of the disk.

Comment: I looked all the anothers questions/answers about it and still doesn't work for me. :(